# Java EE приложение загружает процессор на 100%

Tags: java-ee, tomcat, jboss, профилирование, visualvm

Имеется сервер приложений Jboss EAP 6.4.
Наше приложение иногда загружает сервер на 100%. Работа пользователей становится невозможной.
Практически всегда это происходит во время синхронизации приложения с 1С через веб сервис. 
Складывается впечатление, что приложение съедает ресурсы после получения данных: получаем большой список данных, начинаем записывать его в БД - всё зависает. Но есть нестыковки. Например, иногда данных приходит мало, а проблема всё равно появляется. Иногда наоборот - данных много, но всё работает как часы. 
Использовали visualvm чтобы изучить состояние сервера. Но практически безрезультатно.
Делаю snapshot, фильтрую по нашему пакету, сортирую по total time - вверху списка обычные методы получения данных из бд, которые обычно отрабатывают сравнительно быстро.
Задумывался о блокировках БД, но пока тоже кажется маловероятным. 
Важный момент получение и обработка данных идет в 1 методе, а у процессора 8 ядер. То есть получается **1 поток съедает 8 ядер**, что в общем-то выглядит невозможным. Если у кого-то будут идеи, что делать в этой ситуации, было бы очень здорово.. Прилагаю данные из visual vm собранные в момент загрузки ЦП на 100%

[snapshot.nps](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6aJ6H5VNJ4XRExZYlBCbWc1Zmc)

[threaddump.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6aJ6H5VNJ4XV0VJSGd6ZG5vRnc)

Answer (score 1):

Такие симптомы могут быть из-за проблем с расходом памяти, который приводит к излишней нагрузке на `GC` (`Garbage collection`) - память заканчивается, запускается `GC` и "съедает" 100% `CPU`. Если при этом не удалось высвободить достаточно много памяти, то вскоре `GC` запустится снова. Настройте журнализацию запусков `GC` и мониторьте их. Возможно, что к моменту запуска синхронизации память уже "съедена" другими процессами, и оптимизировать надо их, а не синхронизацию.

Если веб-сервис - `SOAP` - то там высокие накладные расходы на обработку формата `XML`, требуется много памяти и `CPU`: если есть возможность, попробуйте перейти на `REST/JSON`. Проверьте алгоритмы обработки синхронизации, ищите возможность создавать меньше объектов. Если синхронизация получает данные по изменениям с момента предыдущей синхронизации - попробуйте запускать её чаще, чтобы снизить объём данных, передаваемых единовременно.

Поэкспериментируйте с размером доступной приложению памяти (параметр JVM `Xmx`), для промышленного сервера обычно указывают не менее 2-4 Гб. Не торопитесь сразу выделять слишком много памяти, т.к. в таком случае хоть GC, скорее всего, будет запускаться реже, но время его работы может значительно увеличиться - может наступить так называемый `stop the world`, во время которого приложение становится практически не работоспособным. Смотрите так же память сервера - возможно, что ОЗУ закончилось и начинается сброс её содержимого на диск.

Если версия `Java` не самая последняя - попробуйте обновить, т.к. алгоритмы работы `GC` улучшаются от версии к версии. Насколько мне известно в 8-й версии были значительные улучшения. Также существует множество настроек `GC`.

Советы касательно настроек `JVM` - это уже крайний случай: в первую очередь разбирайтесь со своим ПО, т.к. в абсолютном большинстве случаев все проблемы с производительностью кроются именно в прикладном ПО, а не в `JVM`.